# Draw bridge at the intersection of two lines

Tags: fabricjs

I have just started using fabric.js
I can get intersection point of two lines in canvas.

[image]

Now I need to know how can I draw bridge at two lines.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Will you please provide a fiddle with your codes which you have done?? And what do you mean by "draw bridge at two lines""???

Comment: Your question is very ambiguous, please provide more info in order to get help.

Comment: @JayadrathaMondal edited question. Can you help me?

Comment: @BKR edited question. Can you help me?

Comment: @kangax Can you help me in this question?

Comment: @alisoltani, what do you think of my post ? does it help ?

Answer (score 2):

Here's the output that I could get:

[image]

I used the following code (I changed a few things from the original code from http://jsfiddle.net/Q9t6e/):

```
// Multiple_connected_lines_and_curves.js
// this fabric.js demo was based upon the Quadratic Curve demo and the Stickman demo
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('mycanvas');


// ------- points & circles -------

function distance(p1, p2) {
    //Accepts two objects p1 & p2. Returns the distance between p1 & p2
    return Math.sqrt(((p2.left - p1.left) * (p2.left - p1.left)) + ((p2.top - p1.top) * (p2.top - p1.top)));
} // distance()

function addCircle(name, x, y) {

    var c = new fabric.Circle({
        name: name,
        left: x,
        top: y,
        hasBorders: false,
        hasControls: false,
        lockUniScaling: true,
        selectable: true,
        coords: x + ', ' + y,
        reference: true
    });
    return c;
} // addCircle()


function addPoint(name, x, y, style) {

    var p = addCircle(name, x, y, style);;
    p.point = new fabric.Point(x, y);
    p.text = new fabric.Text(name, {
        left: x,
        top: y - 10,
        name: name + '_text',
        fontSize: 14,
        hasBorders: false,
        hasControls: false,
        lockUniScaling: true,
        selectable: false,
        reference: true
    });
    canvas.add(p.text);
    canvas.add(p);
    canvas.bringToFront(p);
    return p;
} // addPoint()


// ------- paths -------

function addLine(p0, p1) {
    var new_line = new fabric.Object();
    new_line = new fabric.Line([p0.left, p0.top, p1.left, p1.top], {
        fill: "black",
        stroke: "black",
        strokeLinejoin: "miter",
        strokeMiterlimit: 1,
        strokeWidth: 1,
        selectable: false,
        hasBorders: false,
        hasControls: false,
        reference: false,
        name: "Line_" + p0.name + p1.name
    });
    if (p0.hasOwnProperty('outPath') === false) {
        p0.outPath = [];
    }
    p0.outPath.push(new_line);
    if (p1.hasOwnProperty('inPath') === false) {
        p1.inPath = [];
    }
    p1.inPath.push(new_line);
    canvas.add(new_line);
    canvas.sendBackwards(new_line);
    canvas.bringToFront(p0);
    canvas.bringToFront(p1);
    return new_line;
} //addLine()

function addCurve(p0, c0, c1, p1) {
    // path are stored as an array of two arrays
    // [['M', p0.left, p0.top], ['C', c0.left, c0.top, c1.left, c1.top, p1.left, p1.top]]
    // [0][0], [0][1], [0][2], [1][0], [1][1], [1][2], [1][3], [1][4], [1][5], [1][6]
    // [0][0] = 'M',   [1][0] = 'C'
    var path_str = 'M ' + p0.left + ' ' + p0.top + ' C ' + c0.left + ' ' + c0.top + ' ' + c1.left + ' ' + c1.top + ' ' + p1.left + ' ' + p1.top;
    var new_path = new fabric.Path(path_str, {
        fill: "",
        stroke: "black",
        strokeLinejoin: "miter",
        strokeMiterlimit: 1,
        strokeWidth: 1,
        hasBorders: false,
        hasControls: false,
        selectable: false,
        reference: false,
        name: 'Curve_' + p0.name + p1.name
    });
    //new_path is an outPath for p0 & c0
    if (p0.hasOwnProperty('outPath') === false) {
        // create p0.outPath array if it doesn't exist
        p0.outPath = [];
    }
    p0.outPath.push(new_path);
    if (c0.hasOwnProperty('outPath') === false) {
        // create c0.outPath array if it doesn't exist
        c0.outPath = [];
    }
    c0.outPath.push(new_path);

    //new_path is an inPath for c1 & p1
    if (c1.hasOwnProperty('inPath') === false) {
        // create c1.inPath array if not exist
        c1.inPath = [];
    }
    c1.inPath.push(new_path);

    if (p1.hasOwnProperty('inPath') === false) {
        // create p1.inPath array if not exist
        p1.inPath = [];
    }
    p1.inPath.push(new_path);

    //draw new_path on canvas
    canvas.add(new_path);
    canvas.bringToFront(p0);
    canvas.bringToFront(p1);
    canvas.bringToFront(c0);
    canvas.bringToFront(c1);
    return new_path;
} //addCurve()


// ------- main -------

// constants
var IN = 90; // 90px per inch
// resize canvas
canvas.setWidth(5 * IN);
canvas.setHeight(5 * IN);
// corner points
var a1 = addPoint('', 1 * IN, 2 * IN);
var a2 = addPoint('', 2 * IN, 1 * IN);
var a3 = addPoint('', 3 * IN, 2 * IN);
var a4 = addPoint('', 2 * IN, 3 * IN);

var a1c11 = addPoint('', 1.9 * IN, 2 * IN);
var a1c12 = addPoint('', 2.1 * IN, 2 * IN);

// control points
a1.c1 = addPoint('', 5 * IN, 1 * IN, 'control');
a1.c2 = addPoint('', 1 * IN, 2 * IN, 'control');
a2.c1 = addPoint('', 2 * IN, 3 * IN, 'control');
a2.c2 = addPoint('', 3 * IN, 2 * IN, 'control');

a1c11.c1 = addPoint('', 2 * IN, 1.85 * IN, 'control');
a1c11.c2 = addPoint('', 2 * IN, 1.85 * IN, 'control');

// draw curves & lines
addCurve(a1c11, a1c11.c1, a1c11.c2, a1c12);
addLine(a4, a2); // vertical line
addLine(a1, a1c11);
addLine(a3, a1c12);


// ------- all objects have been drawn; define observers -------

canvas.observe('object:modified', function (e) {
    //update curves, lines & text when circles are moved
    // lines are accessed using .x1, .y1, .x2, .y2 attributes
    // curves are accessed through its 2 arrays:
    // [0][0] = 'M', [0][1] = po.x, [0][2] = po.y
    // [1][0]='C', [1][1]=c0.x, [1][2]=c0.y, [1][3]=c1.x, [1][4]=c1.y, [1][5]=p1.x, [1][6]=p1.y

    var p = e.target;
    console.log('Moving ' + p.name);

    if (p.hasOwnProperty("text") === true) {
        //move text label to new circle location
        p.text.set({
            'left': p.left,
            'top': p.top - 10
        });
    }

    if (p.hasOwnProperty("inPath") === true) {
        //inpaths - paths end at circle
        for (var i = 0; i < p.inPath.length; i++) {
            ppath = p.inPath[i];
            if (p.ptype === 'control') {
                ppath.path[1][3] = p.left; // p is 2nd control circle in curve, update c1.x
                ppath.path[1][4] = p.top; // p is 2nd control circle in curve, update c1.y
            } else if (ppath.type === 'path') {
                ppath.path[1][5] = p.left; // p is end circle in curve, update p1.x
                ppath.path[1][6] = p.top; // p is end circle in curve update p1.y
            } else if (ppath.type === 'line') {
                ppath.set({
                    'x2': p.left,
                    'y2': p.top
                }); //p is begin circle in line, update left & top
            }
        }
    }
    if (p.hasOwnProperty("outPath") === true) {
        //outpaths - paths begin at circle
        for (var i = 0; i < p.outPath.length; i++) {
            ppath = p.outPath[i];
            if (p.ptype === 'control') {
                ppath.path[1][1] = p.left; //p is 1st control circle in curve, update c0.x
                ppath.path[1][2] = p.top; //p is 1st control circle in curve, update c0.y
            } else if (ppath.type === 'path') {
                ppath.path[0][1] = p.left; // p is begin circle in curve, update p0.x
                ppath.path[0][2] = p.top; // p is begin circle in curve, update p0.y
            } else if (ppath.type === 'line') {
                ppath.set({
                    'x1': p.left,
                    'y1': p.top
                }); //p is end circle in line, update left & top
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(p.name + ' moved!');
    canvas.renderAll();
    canvas.bringToFront(p);
}); //canvas.observe()
```

I did not changed the HTML part and it is here just for reference:

```
<h2>Multiple connected lines and curves</h2>
    <canvas id="mycanvas" width="300" height="300" style="border:2px selectable=false solid #ccc"></canvas>
```

You can change the curve by changing the following variables from the code above:

```
...
var a1c11 = addPoint('', 1.9 * IN, 2 * IN);
var a1c12 = addPoint('', 2.1 * IN, 2 * IN);
...
a1c11.c1 = addPoint('', 2 * IN, 1.85 * IN, 'control');
a1c11.c2 = addPoint('', 2 * IN, 1.85 * IN, 'control');
...
```

Also, in order to see only the line in horizontal with the "bridge" (that you mentioned), just **remove** the following:

```
addLine(a4, a2); // vertical line
```

[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for answering, I solved problem with another method. I get intersection of lines and drew Semicircular with this point and drew white line between intersection points circle and One of the lines. Finally drew  black point at intersection point.

Comment: @AliSoltani it would be nice if you expose your answer